# Sendkeys does not always work with vba

Tags: vba, sendkeys

I have this problem where SendKeys works only at times. I am not able to figure when it works either. I tried using the following commands,

```
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
Application.SendKeys "~"
```

I have also tried adding a timer before as well as after the sendkey command. i tried changing True to False.. but nothing seems to work.

```
lbr = Sheet2.Range("a" & lb).Value
IE.Document.getElementById("sample-1").Value = lbr
IE.Document.getElementById("sample-1").Focus
'Application.SendKeys "~"
 Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
'Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
'Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", False
```

Can someone please suggest a solution or an alternative. 
Thank you..

Comment: Are you sure the appropriate *application* has the focus? Maybe you are sending the ENTER to Excel or the VBE. There must be a better way to "hit" a button.

Comment: for IE integration, look at using HTML Library and internet Controls and use the correct actions, like .Click etc.  Also, rather than a timer, check the IE ready state and its busy property

Comment: @vacip Yeah, In the debug mode the Focus is set on the desired field in the IE window...

Comment: @Nathan_Sav : I've included the readyState code before and after I 
call the Sendkeys function.

    `Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
      DoEvents
    Loop`

Comment: I know the focus is set ont he proper field in the IE object, but is the IE object the program with focus in Windows? Sendkeys just presses enter.

Comment: @vacip: I am relatively new to Vba, can you please let me know how I can check that?

Comment: You look at your monitor... :) Press enter on your keyboard. Which application "gets" it? For example: you have 2 applications running, one on the left side of the screen, the other on the right. Click on the left one, press enter - what happens in the right application? Exactly. Nothing.It is the same shit here. You run a macro from Excel, likely Excel is the active application, so it will get the enter. Use @Nathan_Sav's idea, it is safer and better. Sendkeys is not a good way to deal with things.

Comment: Can you display the website?

Comment: @vacip : Okay,got it.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav : Yeah Nathan I am able to display the website.. I found a 'Filter' button in the webpage and used the 'click' function to get around this issue..

Comment: Howdy, I meant divulge the URL, if you're getting on ok though, all the best, and keep at it :)